# How to generate SQL query for postgres (Redshift) without connection?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I want to build SQL query to pass into [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) reader's "query" option. I'm trying to use psycopg2, so I do something like this:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL(
    "select * from {} where event_timestamp < {}"
).format(
    sql.Identifier("events"),
    sql.Literal(datetime.now())
).as_string()
```

But it tells me that I need to pass context (connection or cursor) to `as_string()`. I'm not able to, because I don't have any connection.

Should I use plain string format in this case with some escaping?

Or is there any way to pass some mock context there? And why it needs connection to build query string? Does SQL query change depending on connection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with spark, but I'd be surprised if they didn't have some kind of sql support. Another alternative is a lightweight package like [sqlbuilder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlbuilder).

If you really want to use psycopg, I suggest looking at how they unit test with mocks -- [psycopg2's ConnectingTestCase](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/tests/testutils.py#L86-L189).

```
class ConnectingTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """A test case providing connections for tests.

    A connection for the test is always available as `self.conn`. Others can be
    created with `self.connect()`. All are closed on tearDown.

    Subclasses needing to customize setUp and tearDown should remember to call
    the base class implementations.
    """
```